# Comparing two arrays and creating third array with common elements

Tags: c++

I need to compare two arrays and output another array that shows common elements.
The output I'm expecting with my code is: 0000056789.
Help will be appreciated.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    const int CE = 10;
    const int TOP = CE-1;


    int iArr1[CE]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int iArr2[CE]={5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14};
    int iArr3[CE]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};



    void main()
    {

        int i;
        int j;
        int iCarr3 = 0;

        for(i=0; i<=TOP; i++)
        {
            for (j=0; j<=TOP; j++)
            {
                if (iArr1[i]==iArr2[j])
                {
                    iCarr3++;
                    iArr3[iCarr3]=iArr2[j];
                }
            }
        }

        cout << iCarr3 << endl;
        cout << iArr3;
        getchar();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you are printing the address of your array
to print the elements of an array

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) // keep track of the size some how
   cout<<iArr3[i]<<" ";
```

P.S: consider sorting the arrays first, and ckecking if `iArr1[i] > iArr2[j]`that way you won't need to scan all the elements on eavh pass

Answer (score 1):

C++ has a [`set_intersection`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) [algorithm](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) in the [Standard Library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    const int CE = 10;
    int iArr1[CE] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int iArr2[CE] = {5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14};
    int iArr3[CE] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    std::set_intersection(std::begin(iArr1), std::end(iArr1),
        std::begin(iArr2), std::end(iArr2),
        std::begin(iArr3));
    std::copy(std::begin(iArr3), std::end(iArr3), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

#### Output

```
5 6 7 8 9 0 0 0 0 0
```

#### Note

If your arrays aren't already sorted, you could put the data into a `std::set` first, since `std::set_intersection()` requires the inputs to be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I hope this is not homework. The way you have it, the output will be 5678900000. For the output to be as you want change your code to be as such:

```
    for(i=0; i<=TOP; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<=TOP; j++)
        {
            if (iArr1[i]==iArr2[j])
            {
                iArr3[iCarr3]=iArr2[j];
            }
        }
        iCarr3++;
    }
```

Then for the output do this:

```
   for(int k = 0; k <= iCarr3; k++)
       std::cout << iArr3[iCarr3] << " ";
```

Comment: It's kind of unethical. Anyways if you have what you want please mark your question as solved.

Comment: Cool, good to know. It's just some stuff they gave me at school for practice, not mandatory to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As your array are sorted, use [`std::set_intersection`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection). Otherwise you just have to [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) them before.

But never forget to use the STD library, the code is a lot more compact and readable... And most of the time less buggy and faster that what you'll come with.

http://ideone.com/c3xE3m

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

const size_t CE = 10;
int iArr1[CE]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int iArr2[CE]={5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14};
int iArr3[CE]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    auto end_elemnt = 
        std::set_intersection(iArr1, iArr1 + CE,
                              iArr2, iArr2 + CE,
                              iArr3);

    std::copy(iArr3, end_elemnt, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
 $ ./a.exe
 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
```